# How do i make update manager work

Tags: package-management, update-manager, repository

This is the error message(below) i get when i try to update through update manager. Can anyone help me with this one?

```
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following commands:

```
sudo rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```